# Which direction to take for creasting wix custom actions?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

Looking for clarity on how to begin writing wix extensions.  Was reading [this page](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/extension_development_simple_example.html), which allows one to begin to create a wix extension for adding custom actions to an installer.

Next, wanting to know how to begin coding up the action itself, I dropped in the old installscript code for one method and began to correct it.  Choking on MsiGetProperty, I wanted to figure out what I needed to import via "using" to make it available.  I then came across [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307499/msisetproperty-from-c-sharp-custom-action) which appears to have other attributes employed which are not referenced on the wix skeleton page.  I then thought, "I wonder if there was a project type for wix extensions made when I instlled it?" and yes, there was!  Code fragment looks like that from the second link, neither of which reflect what is on the wix page...

So, what do I do?  I have several custom actions to port from installshield and just need a solid example of how to construct the project and methods and hook it into my wix xml file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill give you an example of how i do it :

First Create your Custom Action:

```
 [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CreateIisConfigs(Session session)
    {

        try
        {
            LoadXmlFile(session);
            var iisSettings = new IisSettings
            {

                PathName = session["PATHNAME"],
                UserPath = session["USERPATH"],
                Website = session["WEBSITE"],
                SqlDataSource = session["BLOBSQLDATASOURCE"],
                AppPool = session["BLOBAPPLICATIONPOOL"],
                ApplicationName = session["BLOBAPPLICATION"],
                ApplicationPath = @"Sites\Blabla.Application.WebAPI.Blobs",
                EnvirName = session["BLOBENVIRONMENTNAME"],
                EnvirPath = session["ENVIRONMENTPATH"],
                IdentityDomainType = session["BLOBIDENTITYDOMAIN"],
                SitePhysPath = session["SITEPHYSPATH"],
                SqlPass = session["BLOBSQLPASSWORD"],
                SqlUser = session["BLOBSQLUSER"],
                SslCertPath = session["SSLCERTPATH"],
                SslCertPass = session["SSLCERTPASS"],
                UserAppl = session["BLOBUSERAPPLICATION"],

            };
            IisConfigs.ApplyNewConfigs(iisSettings);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            session.Log("----------------------------------------IIS ERROR ---------------------------------------");
            session.Log(e.ToString());
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }


        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

Then in your wxs initialise the properties etc.. :

```
 <Property Id="PATHNAME"  Hidden="yes"/>
<Property Id ="WEBSITE" Hidden="yes"/>
<Property Id="SITEPHYSPATH" Hidden="yes"/>
<Property Id="USERPATH" Hidden="yes"/>
```

Declare your Binary which references to the dll or the custom action :

```
 <Binary Id="CustomActionsId" SourceFile="..\Blob.CustomActions\bin\Debug\Blob.CustomActions.CA.dll"/>
```

Declare your custom action :

```
  <CustomAction Id="CreateIisConfigs" BinaryKey="CustomActionsId"  Return="check" Execute="immediate" DllEntry="CreateIisConfigs" />
```

Last decide how the custom action will execute :

```
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CreateIisConfigs" Before="InstallInitialize">NOT Install</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```